# Need help in Event Handling

Tags: c#, .net, generics, event-handling, delegates

I have a delegate

```
delegate string Mathop<T,F>(T a,F b);
```

and I am declaring an event like

```
event Mathop<T,F> someevent;
```

But here I am getting an error. It says 'T' could not be found. I want my `Mathop` delegate to work as an eventhandler for my event.

What I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose the event in a class which takes type parameters e.g.

```
class C<T, F>
{
    event Mathop<T, F> someevent;
}
```

You can't subscribe to an event that doesn't have concrete types defined - imagine if you could - you could add any delegate to that event as long as it took two parameters and returned a string!

With the above code, you should now be able to do something like

```
new C<Int32, Int32>().someevent += MyMethod
```

where MyMethod has the signature

```
String MyMethod(Int32 a, Int32 b);
```